# mysql charsets, can I perform the conversion in python?

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a MySQL database which contains some bad data.

I start with this Unicode string:

```
u'TECNOLOGÍA Y EDUCACIÓN'
```

Encoding to UTF-8 for the database yields:

```
'TECNOLOG\xc3\x8dA Y EDUCACI\xc3\x93N'
```

When I send these bytes to the database, using connection charset `latin1` and database charset `utf8` (yes, I know this is wrong, but this has already happened, many, many times, and the goal now is to figure out the exact process of corruption so it can be reversed), the data is converted to this (checked using `BINARY()`):

```
'TECNOLOG\xc3\x83\xc2\x8dA Y EDUCACI\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9cN'
```

Double-encoding aside, the result I'd expect here is:

```
'TECNOLOG\xc3\x83\xc2\x8dA Y EDUCACI\xc3\x83\xc2\x93N'
```

Most of this makes sense, as it is interpreting the multi-byte UTF-8 chars as latin1, and encoding each byte as an individual char, but the conversion of `\x93` -> `\xe2\x80\x9c` makes no sense. latin1's `\x93` does not convert to UTF-8 `\xe2\x80\x9c`, although `\xe2\x80\x9c` can be converted to Unicode, yielding `u'\u201c'`, which is codepoint `\x93` in the CP-1252 charset.

Is mysql combining latin1 and CP-1252 when it handles conversions? How can I replicate the conversion process entirely in python? I've iterated through every encoding on the system and none of them work for the entire string. How, in python, can I get from `'TECNOLOG\xc3\x83\xc2\x8dA Y EDUCACI\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9cN'` back to `'TECNOLOG\xc3\x8dA Y EDUCACI\xc3\x93N'`?  Decoding as UTF-8 will handle the first 3/4ths correctly, but that last one is just wrong, and nothing I've tried will return the correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > the goal now is to figure out the exact process of corruption so it can be reversed

   As documented under [`ALTER TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html):

   > #### Warning
   >
   > The `CONVERT TO` operation converts column values between the character sets. This is not what you want if you have a column in one character set (like `latin1`) but the stored values actually use some other, incompatible character set (like `utf8`). In this case, you have to do the following for each such column:
   >
   > ```
   > ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 BLOB;
   > ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
   > ```
   >
   > The reason this works is that there is no conversion when you convert to or from BLOB columns.

   In your case:

   1. change the column's encoding to the connection character set that was used on insertion (i.e. `latin1`), so that the stored bytes become the same as those that were originally received:

      ```
      ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY my_column TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1;
      ```
   2. then drop the encoding information (by modifying the column so that it becomes a binary string):

      ```
      ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY my_column BLOB;
      ```
   3. then apply the correct encoding information (by modifying the column so that it becomes a character string in the `utf8` character set):

      ```
      ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY my_column TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
      ```

   Be careful to use datatypes of sufficient length to avoid data truncation.  Also be careful to ensure that application code thenceforth uses the correct connection character set (or else you may end up with a table where some records are encoded in one manner and others in another, which can be a nightmare to resolve).

   If you cannot modify the database just yet, simply fetching data whilst the connection character is set to `latin1` (but with your application expecting UTF-8) will yield correct data.  Or else, use [`CONVERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-convert.html):

   ```
   SELECT CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(my_column USING latin1) USING utf8)
   FROM   my_table
   ```
2. > Is mysql combining latin1 and cp1252 when it handles conversions?

   As documented under [West European Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-we-sets.html):

   > MySQL's `latin1` is the same as the Windows `cp1252` character set. This means it is the same as the official `ISO 8859-1` or IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority) `latin1`, except that IANA `latin1` treats the code points between `0x80` and `0x9f` as “undefined,” whereas `cp1252`, and therefore MySQL's `latin1`, assign characters for those positions. For example, `0x80` is the Euro sign. For the “undefined” entries in `cp1252`, MySQL translates `0x81` to Unicode `0x0081`, `0x8d` to `0x008d`, `0x8f` to `0x008f`, `0x90` to `0x0090`, and `0x9d` to `0x009d`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering, because the \x8d in my example above was preventing me from decoding, so I assumed it was some sort of frankenstein charset. Looks like I was right. Thanks for the amazingly fast response!

Comment: If mysql thinks it can convert \x8d, and python thinks it can't, then that's enough additions for me to consider it a frankenstein. That \x8d was the only thing making me think it wasn't cp1252, because every other record was reversible using cp1252. If mysql didn't have those additions, this question would never have been posted. :D

Comment: @GeraldThibault: Ah yes, quite right.  Still, one can perform the conversion in MySQL as shown under point #1 in my answer above.